# <C-space> doesn't work in neovim in PowerShell in Windows terminal

Tags: powershell, vim-plugin, neovim, windows-terminal

everyone!

I’m configuring neovim for “Windows terminal”. And I installed the coc plugin. And I would like to use  for triggering suggestions like in VSC. But the problem is that  in neovim doesn't work at all.

This is the remap I try to use:

```
" Use <c-space> to trigger completion.
if has('nvim')
    inoremap <silent><expr> <c-space> coc#refresh()
else
    inoremap <silent><expr> <c-@> coc#refresh()
endif
```

I tried:

```
inoremap <silent><expr> <Nul> coc#refresh()
inoremap <silent><expr> <c-@> coc#refresh()
```

and they don’t work either.

Also I tried to check if  works with other remaps:

```
inoremap <c-@> print<cr>
inoremap <c-space> print<cr>
inoremap <Nul> print<cr>
```

And even directly with powershell, command prompt, bash and cmder terminals it didn’t type “print” text.

And BTW ctrl+space works directly in “windows terminal” and PowerShell as autocomplete. Can someone tell me please, is it neovim or terminal issue?

Did someone solve this problem previously?

I discovered the internet before posting and the only thing I found is this 2 years old [article](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/fyg1ma/how_to_find_out_whats_stopping_cspace_to_trigger/) and it didn’t help.

Comment: Maybe powershell is sending the wrong sequence to nvim and nvim can not parse it. Try git-bash instead, works for me.

Comment: directly in git bash it shows black terminal now. Previously it isn't, need to fix it.

Comment: In WT it opens neovim in git bash but <C-space> doesn't work. Previously I tried cmd and git bash directly it didn't work. Will check again, thank you.

Comment: I considered to use WSL for neovim. What do you think, is it good idea? @jdhao

Comment: Using nvim inside git-bash inside WT, <C-space> does not work for me either. Using git-bash directly works. WSL is pretty good, but I haven't used it extensively, can say for sure. I think your best option is to use a Neovim GUI, terminal in Windows sucks in various ways.

Comment: @AndrewO. - did you ever solve this? I'm hitting the same issue. I've tried NVim in Powershell in WT, I've tried it in normal Powershell (not WT), I've tried it from Cmd. None work.

Comment: No, I didn't. Unfortunately.

Comment: Looks like it might be this neovim bug: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/8435

Comment: @Dan seems like :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about "Windows and Powershell" But ctrl+y works for me.
I made it easier for myself and just remapped ctrl+y.
`inoremap

Comment: inoremap <c-j> <c-y>

Comment: I get used to <c-space> in VSC, and would really want to have same in nvim.